# Cargo test--failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.9`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to compile a Rust project on Windows by using Visual Studio code. But the compiling has error. I have double checked my cargo version which is the latest.

C:\Users\Lenovo>rustc -V                                                                                                rustc 1.55.0 (c8dfcfe04 2021-09-06)
C:\Users\Lenovo>cargo -V                                                                                                cargo 1.55.0 (32da73ab1 2021-08-23)
Here is the detail:

```
PS D:\334f21blockchain\Warmup2> cargo test
   Compiling ring v0.16.9
error: failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.9`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `D:\334f21blockchain\target\debug\build\ring-b7fec9a4b28b2dd2\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)       
  

--- stdout
  ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  APPDATA: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming
  CARGO: \\?\C:\Users\Lenovo\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin\cargo.exe
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ARCH: x86_64
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENDIAN: little
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENV: msvc
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FAMILY: windows
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE: fxsr,sse,sse2
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS: windows
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_POINTER_WIDTH: 64
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_VENDOR: pc
  CARGO_CFG_WINDOWS:
  CARGO_ENCODED_RUSTFLAGS:
  CARGO_FEATURE_ALLOC: 1
  CARGO_FEATURE_DEFAULT: 1
  CARGO_FEATURE_DEV_URANDOM_FALLBACK: 1
  CARGO_FEATURE_LAZY_STATIC: 1
  CARGO_HOME: C:\Users\Lenovo\.cargo
  CARGO_MAKEFLAGS: -j --jobserver-fds=__rust_jobserver_semaphore_131125572 --jobserver-auth=__rust_jobserver_semaphore_131125572
  CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR: C:\Users\Lenovo\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\ring-0.16.9
  CARGO_MANIFEST_LINKS: ring-asm
  CARGO_PKG_AUTHORS: Brian Smith <brian@briansmith.org>
  CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION: Safe, fast, small crypto using Rust.
  CARGO_PKG_HOMEPAGE:
  CARGO_PKG_LICENSE:
  CARGO_PKG_LICENSE_FILE: LICENSE
  CARGO_PKG_NAME: ring
  CARGO_PKG_REPOSITORY: https://github.com/briansmith/ring
  CARGO_PKG_VERSION: 0.16.9
  CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MAJOR: 0
  CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MINOR: 16
  CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PATCH: 9
  CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PRE:
  CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_4864_VIZIBUEZHKKHILJA
  CLASSPATH: .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\lib
  CLION: D:\CLion 2021.2.2\bin;
  COLORTERM: truecolor
  COMMONPROGRAMFILES: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  COMMONPROGRAMW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  COMPUTERNAME: DESKTOP-9LKHU0G
  COMSPEC: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
  DEBUG: true
  DRIVERDATA: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
  ERLANG_HOME: C:\Program Files\erl9.3
  FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING: Internet Explorer
  FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING: Default
  GDAL_DATA: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\gdal-data
  GIT_ASKPASS: d:\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\askpass.sh
  GOOGLE_API_KEY: no
  GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID: no
  GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET: no
  HOME: C:\Users\Lenovo
  HOMEDRIVE: C:
  HOMEPATH: \Users\Lenovo
  HOST: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  INTELLIJ IDEA: D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2\bin;
  JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2
  LANG: en_US.UTF-8
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH: C:\Users\Lenovo\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib
  LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local
  LOGONSERVER: \\DESKTOP-9LKHU0G
  MAVEN_HOME: D:\apache-maven-3.8.2
  NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
  NUM_JOBS: 4
  ONEDRIVE: C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive
  OPT_LEVEL: 0
  ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: undefined
  OS: Windows_NT
  OUT_DIR: D:\334f21blockchain\target\debug\build\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\out
  PATH: D:\334f21blockchain\target\debug\deps;D:\334f21blockchain\target\debug;C:\Users\Lenovo\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib;C:\Users\Lenovo\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\Lenovo\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;D:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;G:\Git\cmd;G:\Git\mingw64\bin;G:\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\lib;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;G:\texlive\2020\bin\win32;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\;D:\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin;G:\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\Lenovo\.cargo\bin;D:\anaconda3;D:\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;D:\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;D:\anaconda3\Library\bin;D:\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;G:\PyCharm 2019.2.3\bin;;G:\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\bin;;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2\bin;;C:\Users\Lenovo\.dotnet\tools;D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\CLion 2021.2.2\bin;
  PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
  POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS: 1
  POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS: GTiff PNG JPEG GIF XYZ DTED USGSDEM AAIGrid
  PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  PROCESSOR_REVISION: 8e09
  PROFILE: debug
  PROGRAMDATA: C:\ProgramData
  PROGRAMFILES: C:\Program Files
  PROGRAMFILES(X86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  PROGRAMW6432: C:\Program Files
  PSMODULEPATH: C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;
  PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  PYCHARM: G:\PyCharm 2019.2.3\bin;
  PYCHARM COMMUNITY EDITION: G:\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\bin;
  RUSTC: rustc
  RUSTDOC: rustdoc
  RUSTUP_HOME: C:\Users\Lenovo\.rustup
  RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN: stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  RUST_RECURSION_COUNT: 1
  SESSIONNAME: Console
  SYSTEMDRIVE: C:
  SYSTEMROOT: C:\WINDOWS
  TARGET: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  TEMP: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp
  TERM_PROGRAM: vscode
  TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: 1.60.2
  TMP: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp
  USERDOMAIN: DESKTOP-9LKHU0G
  USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: DESKTOP-9LKHU0G
  USERNAME: Lenovo
  USERPROFILE: C:\Users\Lenovo
  VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN: d:\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\askpass-main.js
  VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE: D:\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe
  VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE: \\.\pipe\vscode-git-44e0e6a769-sock
  WINDIR: C:\WINDOWS
  running: "D:\\Visual Studio 2019\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\lib.exe" "-out:D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\libring-core.a" "-nologo" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\aes-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\aesni-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\vpaes-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\x86_64-mont-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\x86_64-mont5-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\chacha-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\p256-x86_64-asm-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\aesni-gcm-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\ghash-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\poly1305-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\sha512-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\sha256-x86_64-nasm.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\generic.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\montgomery.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\montgomery_inv.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\crypto.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\ecp_nistz.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\ecp_nistz256.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\gfp_p256.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\gfp_p384.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\limbs.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\mem.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\gcm.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\curve25519.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\cpu-intel.obj"
  D:\334f21blockchain\target\debug\build\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\out\generic.obj : fatal error LNK1112: ???????"x86"????????"x64"??
  exit code: 1112

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "D:\\Visual Studio 2019\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\lib.exe" "-out:D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\libring-core.a" "-nologo" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\aes-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\aesni-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\vpaes-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\x86_64-mont-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\x86_64-mont5-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\chacha-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\p256-x86_64-asm-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\aesni-gcm-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\ghash-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\poly1305-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\sha512-x86_64-nasm.obj" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.16.9\\pregenerated\\sha256-x86_64-nasm.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\generic.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\montgomery.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\montgomery_inv.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\crypto.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\ecp_nistz.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\ecp_nistz256.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\gfp_p256.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\gfp_p384.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\limbs.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\mem.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\gcm.obj" 
"D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\curve25519.obj" "D:\\334f21blockchain\\target\\debug\\build\\ring-b4ab554b08e569c3\\out\\cpu-intel.obj" with args "lib.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1112).
```